# Javamail: Multiple Threads Opening a Folder in Read Write Mode is Blocked

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am writing a multi-threaded app to handle incoming email. I have one thread reading the Inbox messages and then farming them out to other threads which process the message (thread per message).  I am connecting to Exchange 2013 (v.15) with all current updates.

The Store connection is being closed and when I try to re-open it I am getting an exception which states "failed to create new store connection".  This is happening on the folder.exists() call.  The folder definately exists.

I am opening in R/W mode because I have to move the messages to other folders as they are being processed.

The app runs for a while and then this starts happening.  We've bumped up every setting we could find in Exchange to allow as many connections as possible.  I'm wonderng if Exchange is only allowing 1 Read_Write connection to a folder?

We are doing IMAP (SSL)

Note: we are not a spammer.

Exception:

```
javax.mail.StoreClosedException: failed to create new store connection
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.throwClosedException(IMAPFolder.java:3368)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.doCommand(IMAPFolder.java:3497)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.exists(IMAPFolder.java:560)
at com.myco.myapp.MessageHandler.getFolder(MessageHandler.java:68)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on [JavaMail session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).  The debug output might provide more clues as to why JavaMail can't connect to the server, or why the server is refusing the login attempt.

Are you running any firewall or anti-virus software that might be interfering with the connection attempt?

It would be easy to write a program to test whether Exchange allows more than one read/write connection to the same folder.

Comment: I can certainly turn on protocol debug and I will try that.  And I can write an app to test connections but I think the issue is Exchange doing resource management and throttling.  The app works for a while and then connections are refused.  I will get the debug output in the meantime.

Comment: Yes, it may be a problem at the Exchange end that you can't control from the client.